# Can not upload file when using a swagger generated spring server

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I want to implement a file readout function on my REST Service. Since I do not know how to use spring myself, I use swagger to generate the server code for me. Normally this works perfectly fine, but when I try to upload files I get the following error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-11-07T12:27:43.119Z",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception":   "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException",
"message": "Required request part 'file' is not present",
"path": "/requirements/import"
}
```

My yaml uses the following lines for the import function:

```
/requirements/import:
post:
  consumes:
  - multipart/form-data
  description:
    Returns all requirements contained in the submitted reqIf file.
  parameters:
  - name: reqIfFile
    in: formData
    type: file
    description: The reqIf file that contains the requirements.
  responses:
    200:
      description: An array of requirements.
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: 'requirement'
```

The generated interface (with some added exceptions):

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2018-04-05T07:19:00.887Z")

@Api(value = "requirements", description = "the requirements API")
public interface RequirementsApi {

@ApiOperation(value = "", nickname = "requirementsImportPost", notes = "Returns all requirements contained in the submitted reqIf file.", response = Requirement.class, responseContainer = "List", tags = {})
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "An array of requirements.", response = Requirement.class, responseContainer = "List") })
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping(value = "/requirements/import", produces = { "application/json" }, consumes = {
        "multipart/form-data" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<List<Requirement>> requirementsImportPost(
        @ApiParam(value = "file detail") @Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile reqIfFile)
        throws IOException, ContinuumException;
```

}

The code that actually does the readout:

```
@javax.annotation.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2018-04-05T07:19:00.887Z")

@Controller
public class RequirementsApiController implements RequirementsApi {

@Override
public ResponseEntity<List<Requirement>> requirementsImportPost(
        @ApiParam(value = "file detail") @Valid @RequestPart("file") final MultipartFile reqIfFile)
        throws IOException, ContinuumException {

    InputStream fileStream = new BufferedInputStream(reqIfFile.getInputStream());
    List<Requirement> list = ReadReqIF.readReqIfFile(fileStream);
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Requirement>>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Can someone tell me where a possible error is?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with my swagger generated spring server.

I was able to workaround the problem by modifying the generated server code to change the name "file" in @RequestPart("file") to the name specified in the swagger spec. In your case, it should be @RequestPart("reqIfFile"). It'd have to be modified in both the interface and controller code.

There is likely a bug in the Spring server generator code in Swagger editor. I can't think of any other reason for the RequestPart annotation to be named "file" which is essentially the "type" and not name of the parameter.

Comment: Sadly, this did not solve my issue. The new error message just statest "reqIfFile is not present"